# When toggling between components with Framer Motion's AnimatePresence, exit animations don't seem to happen

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

An example of this is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-moon-1wrmgp?file=/src/App.js

Click the toggle button to switch between two different components being rendered.

You'll notice that despite the incredibly long duration set for the transition, this only seems to apply for mounting animations. Components unmounting don't have a similarly timed exit animation. In fact, there doesn't seem to be an exit animation at all.

Why is this?

Comment: Using the ternary in this way immediately destroys the DOM nodes. It does not have time to show the hide animation

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I thought this was the point of mount/unmount transitions. I'm struggling to understand the point of the exit property if that were the case. The official documentation shows a similar example where the component is immediately removed: https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs: https://www.framer.com/motion/animate-presence/##exit-animations

"Direct children must each have a unique key prop so AnimatePresence can track their presence in the tree."

Change it to have the keys as the direct children and it will work

```
<AnimatePresence>{aOrB ? <A key="A" /> : <B key="B" />}</AnimatePresence>
```

Comment: Thank you! I naively thought a key in the component definition would be enough, but now it seems obvious that this isn't the case.